# SVN External failed due to authorization issues but can't figure out why

Tags: svn, authorization, svn-externals

I've got a repo setup with 3 projects(1 per folder) and a 4th folder with some supporting DLL code in it.  In each of the 3 projects I have setup svn:externals to this supporting DLL folder.
When I try to update any of the main projects I get the message (TortoiseSVN) "External Failed, unreadable path encountered, access denied."

Here is my repo layout:

_MY_REPO
--Project1/trunk (with svn:externals -r7 ^/SupportingDLLs/trunk Common)
--Project2/trunk (with svn:externals -r7 ^/SupportingDLLs/trunk Common)
--Project3/trunk (with svn:externals -r7 ^/SupportingDLLs/trunk Common)
--SupportingDLLs/trunk

With the following authz file I get the error message mentioned:
[/]
myUserName = rw

With this authz file it all works fine
[/]
* = r
myUserName = rw

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

According to [**the Book**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html), externals need a full URL (emphasis mine):

> It can be set on any versioned directory, and its value is a multi-line table of subdirectories (relative to the versioned directory on which the property is set) and **fully qualified, absolute Subversion repository URLs**.

Comment: Not since 1.5, which supports relative paths. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have

```
anon-access = none
```

in your `conf/svnserve.conf` file, and maybe you are accessing the external repository anonymously rather than with your username.

Comment: Micheal I don't think its that, as I have both lines commented out which I assume makes the config go to default, which is stated as what is defined below anyway.
# anon-access = read
# auth-access = write

BTW, what is the priority of authentication, does the svnserve.conf file come before the authz, or the other way round.